# Kdenlive snap version doesn't render in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, snap, dbus, kdenlive

When I'm trying to render a project, it just stuck on 'Waiting' and render never starts.
Console log contains next error:

```
starting kdenlive_render process using:  "/snap/kdenlive/26/usr/bin/kdenlive_render"
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
dbus[11474]: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "_dbus_check_is_valid_path (path)" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1366.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Probably an issue with the packaging of the Snap. You may want to use the APT version or the AppImage instead.

Comment: Unfortunately APT version is pretty old: 17.x.x against 20.x.x in snap version. Don't want to upgrade whole system just to get newest APT kdenlive tbh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be an issue with the snap package available. Unless this is fixed, you will not be able to use that version. Likely, the regular APT version will work, but as you are still using Ubuntu 18.04, the version that comes with that version will be quite old. Note that Ubuntu 18.04, while still receives maintenance updates, will be EOL next year in 2022.

- If, despite wanting to stick with an older version of the operating system, you want the newest version of KDEnlive, you are in luck. The developpers of KDEnlive [package their releases](https://kdenlive.org/en/download) in an [AppImage](https://appimage.github.io/). An AppImage is an application distribution format where all dependencies are contained inside a single file. Therefore, the same AppImage can be run on a number of Linux distributions, including Ubuntu 18.04. Running an AppImage is as simple as downloading the `.AppImage` file, and running that file after you have set the executable bit (right-click, "Properties" tab in your file manager).
- Another option would be to [enable Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/) on your operating system and install KDEnlive as a flatpak.
- For technically very skilled users, compiling the program yourself based on the source code also remains an option.

Comment: AppImage works for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Kdenlive snap would never render for me until I installed it with the confinement of --devmode.
sudo snap install kdenlive --devmode
It still says waiting, but it actually renders to the folder you set it to.